# Opengl C++: How do I make parts of a texture transparent?

Tags: c++, opengl, user-interface

I'm making  a GUI class in my Opengl project. Currently what I am doing is I create a plane and then I bind a bmp texture to it. Is there a way to make parts of it transparent?

Right now this is what shows up (the white/blue box in the bottom left): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZpjy.jpg

I want the image to just show the blue area.

This is my code if you would like to take a look:

```
// Struct of bitmap file.
struct BitMapFile
{
   int sizeX;
   int sizeY;
   unsigned char *data;
};

// Routine to read a bitmap file.
// Works only for uncompressed bmp files of 24-bit color.
BitMapFile *getBMPData(string filename)
{
   BitMapFile *bmp = new BitMapFile;
   unsigned int size, offset, headerSize;

   // Read input file name.
   ifstream infile(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

   // Get the starting point of the image data.
   infile.seekg(10);
   infile.read((char *) &offset, 4); 

   // Get the header size of the bitmap.
   infile.read((char *) &headerSize,4);

   // Get width and height values in the bitmap header.
   infile.seekg(18);
   infile.read( (char *) &bmp->sizeX, 4);
   infile.read( (char *) &bmp->sizeY, 4);

   // Allocate buffer for the image.
   size = bmp->sizeX * bmp->sizeY * 24;
   bmp->data = new unsigned char[size];

   // Read bitmap data.
   infile.seekg(offset);
   infile.read((char *) bmp->data , size);

   // Reverse color from bgr to rgb.
   int temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 3)
   { 
      temp = bmp->data[i];
      bmp->data[i] = bmp->data[i+2];
      bmp->data[i+2] = temp;
   }

   return bmp;
}

class GUI
{
public:
    GUI();
    GUI(float x, float y, float width, float height, string textureName);

    void LoadTexture(string textureName);

    void Draw();

    float GetCenterX() { return m_CenterX; }
    float GetCenterY() { return m_CenterY; }
    void SetCenterX(float value) { m_CenterX = value; }
    void SetCenterY(float value) { m_CenterY = value; }

private:
    float m_CenterX, m_CenterY, m_Width, m_Height, m_Depth;
    unsigned int m_Texture[1];
    unsigned char m_Colour[3];
    string m_TextureName;

};

GUI::GUI(float x, float y, float width, float height, string textureName)
{
    m_CenterX = x;
    m_CenterY = y;
    m_Width = width;
    m_Height = height;
    m_Depth = 0.0; 
    m_TextureName = textureName;
    LoadTexture(textureName);
}

void GUI::Draw()
{
    // Turn on OpenGL texturing.
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

     // Activate a texture.
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture[0]); 

    // Map the texture onto a square polygon.
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(m_CenterX - m_Width, m_CenterY - m_Height, -5.0001);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(m_CenterX + m_Width, m_CenterY - m_Height, -5.0001);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(m_CenterX + m_Width, m_CenterY + m_Height, -5.0001);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(m_CenterX - m_Width, m_CenterY + m_Height, -5.0001);
   glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void GUI::LoadTexture(string textureName)           
{
    // Create texture index array.
    glGenTextures(1, m_Texture); 

   // Local storage for bmp image data.
   BitMapFile *image[1];

   // Load the texture.
   image[0] = getBMPData(textureName);

   // Bind image to texture index[0]. 
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture[0]); 
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

   //used to make the image look blocky
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);

   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image[0]->sizeX, image[0]->sizeY, 0, 
                GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image[0]->data);
}

void drawScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    GUI(-3,-3,1,1,0.3,"lifebar.bmp").Draw();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void setup(void) 
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
    // Specify how texture values combine with current surface color values.
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Comment: you should start by adding a alpha component to the texture

Comment: @ratchetfreak how do I add the alpha component?

Comment: Easiest way is to load RGBA images, where alpha (A) channel is already present and hopefully correct. Other possibilities include creating separate alpha channels ("grayscale" image), but I don't know how to use them with fixed pipeline (assuming you are not using your own custom shader).

Comment: Looking at photoshop I see that it won't allow me to save the .bmp with an alpha for some reason. The option is grayed out and I can't find a reason why. I have been trying to get away from the fixed pipeline because I keep hearing how bad it is. I've been trying to find a good tutorial on vertex arrays or something, but alas I can't find anything on it that will give a clear answer. Any suggestions for both of these issues?

Comment: I have not used Photoshop, so I don't know about that, but I'm pretty sure that it is not only able to save alpha channels, probably it has also tools to create them.

Fixed function pipeline is not bad, just slow compared to modern approach, but on the other side, you also get something working quicker. Moving to modern OpenGL may require some amount of code before things start happening. I have used these tutorials to learn things:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

Comment: @MaKo What do you use to create alpha channels? I can;t seem to find a solution to make my .bmp transparent in photoshop. i will take a look at those, thank you. I have it working, I want it to be more efficient now.

Comment: I have mainly 3 sources for images: (1) downloaded RGBA images (for testing, placeholders etc) already having them, (2) generated bitmaps where I put that when generating one, and (3) text/glyph bitmaps, which get alpha channel when rendering font (with function that creates one). If I draw something by myself, I choose format that has alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Quickly and simply, you need:

1) Alpha channel describing pixel transparency: Easiest way is to load RGBA image.

2) Enable alpha blending:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Choose blending function depending on your needs.

**EDIT:** Notice, that when using RGBA images, change both texture and image format correctly (GL_RGB -> GL_RGBA):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image[0]->sizeX, image[0]->sizeY, 0, 
            GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image[0]->data);
```

**EDIT2:** I have code to create 1x1 bitmap from color value. I use this to create dummy color and normal maps for objects that do not have that. For your testing purposes, create texture from buffer like this (this is D source, you should be able to convert it to C++ quite easily):

```
this(vec4 color) // Create texture from color value
{
    ubyte[] buffer = [
        cast(ubyte)(color.r*255),
        cast(ubyte)(color.g*255),
        cast(ubyte)(color.b*255),
        cast(ubyte)(color.a*255)
    ];
    this(1, 1, buffer.ptr, GL_RGBA); // Width, height, image buffer, image format
}
```

Using this texture, when everything works well, you should be able to create arbitrary sized rectangles on screen. Change alpha values to see that blending works.

**EDIT3:** The code above written with C++-like pseudocode:

```
BitMapFile *createSinglePixelBitmap()
{
    static unsigned char pixel[4] = { 255, 0, 0, 125 }; // Red pixel, alpha ~ 50%
    BitMapFile *bitmap = new BitMapFile;

    bitmap.sizeX = 1;
    bitmap.sizeY = 1;
    bitmap.data = pixel;

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: I have the glenable already. When I add the glBlendFunc this happens: http://imgur.com/MhZKcaR. Any idea why it is doing that?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork try to change `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` to `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`. Also check if your context has an alpha buffer

Comment: @Nazar554 I changed it, but it is still giving me the same issue. What do you mean by context?

Comment: You create window somehow, and at that you most probably also create opengl context. I use SDL to create it, so I use SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8) just to make sure that it creates alpha layer for the context.

Comment: Anyways, those are pretty much everything I need to do to enable alpha blending for HUD & transparent 3D objects.

Comment: @Nazar554 You don't need a framebuffer with alpha for blend functions that  use `SRC_ALPHA`. That's only needed if the blend function includes `DST_ALPHA`.

Comment: @MaKo I sort of understand. To create my window I use glut because that is what was in my tutorials when I was learning. How would I set the attribute for that?  This is my main function: http://codepad.org/QDE6NCdw

Comment: @MaKo: `GL_SRC_ALPHA` refers to the alpha component of the source fragment (i.e. the output of a fragment shader). `GL_DST_ALPHA` refers to the alpha component of the destination pixel (framebuffer). Traditional alpha blending does not need the framebuffer to store alpha, it is based entirely on the alpha component of the source fragment.

Comment: @Nazar554 and Andon, thanks for clarifying that! For WhyYouNoWork, as others said, you don't need to change that, you just need alpha channel for your bitmap, and enable blending. My knowledge about the subject is limited, I put on my answer just about everything I do to enable blending when needed :/ I had problems at first to make it work, but they were mainly up to choosing image and texture formats and such.

Comment: @MaKo I have added the glBlendFunc to my setup (its right below my blend). I have also changed the RGB to RGBA in that function, but am still having an issue. It is rendering an image, but it still shows  a white background and now the colours are in a strange colour and pattern: http://imgur.com/1Z2cLvT Any ideas?

Comment: As said, my knowledge in this area is limited. Make sure that your bitmap is correct RGBA bitmap, with correct alpha values, make sure to specify correct formats to glTexImage2D, make sure that you have blending enabled and using correct blending function. Blending started to work in my project pretty easily and I haven't touched that part after that, so I'm not familiar with all the problems it may have.

Comment: @MaKo I know there is an alpha channel in image, but I'm not sure how to check my images alpha value. Any suggestions? If there were no alpha value then the image would look like the off air screen you used to see on tvs. I have changed my glTexImage2D to take in RGBA and i have included the blend and blendfun. changing either of those will cause it to stop rendering anything altogether which I don't really understand. Looking at your code I'm a bit lost. I don't know D source. Could you explain how it works.

Comment: You should see if bitmap is transparent in your favored image editor/viewer, they usually have chessboard background indicating it. I added creation of single pixel bitmap with C++ -like pseudocode (that is, I can't guarantee it is legal C++).

Comment: @MaKo I have added that function to my program and changed my loadtexture function to call it. It seems to make the 1 pixel texture, but the problem is my box still doesn't become transparent, Any idea why? This is that happens: http://imgur.com/a/Ttgft

Comment: Your screenshot does not contain anything behind the box, so it's pretty hard to guess if it is half-transparent (as it should be). Try putting it over something and post screenshot (or change alpha to 0, then it should be invisible).

Comment: @MaKo I created a new gui layer to go over the original. It looks like they are both the same colour. I don't see any transparency: http://imgur.com/Ea1Rafj

Comment: @MaKo i have a feeling that the code is fine, but it might not like that I am rendering a texture on a solid plane. Is there a way to make part of that plane transparent?

Comment: Yes, no transparency in screenshot, the overlapping section should be visible. I don't have any other ideas - at least at the moment - to try out.